# MongoDb : Find objects with only date filter

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In mongodb I have datetime field like "2018-01-26T16:40:19.305+05:00"
How I will filter with today's date only?. I mean without time?

My document:

```
{
    "pk": NumberLong("6585118137"),
    "created_time": ISODate("2018-01-26T16:40:19.305+05:00"),
}
```

I want something like

```
select * from table where date(created_time) = "2018-01-26"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can compare the date is `$gte` `new Date("2018-01-26")` and `$lt` `new Date("2018-01-27")`

```
db.col.find( 
    {$expr : 
        { $and: [ { $gte : ["$created_time", new Date("2018-01-26")] }, { $lt : [ "$created_time", new Date("2018-01-27") ] } ] } 
    } 
)
```

or format date to `%Y%m%d` (yyyyMMdd) and compare with date string to be searched

```
db.col.find(
    {$expr : 
        {$eq :
            [{$dateToString: {format: '%Y%m%d',date: "$created_time"}}, "20180126"]
        }
    }
)
```